# springboot with tomcat datasource

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, datasource

It`s possible to use tomcat datasource with springboot in develop mode?

I want to configure my project to use tomcat datasource so, when I create one .war and deploy at my tomcat client that have datasource configured works fine

but how can I use this with mvn spring-boot:run?

Comment: You could configure Spring Boot to use your [JNDI DataSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connecting-to-a-jndi-datasource) referencing your Tomcat datasource.

Comment: But how I create the datasource in tomcat when I develop? because the tomcat are embedded

Comment: I suppose you can avoid creating the executable jar by packaging your Spring Boot application [as a war](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file) and then deploy that war into a Tomcat instance in which you have  [defined the data source](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#JDBC_Data_Sources).

Comment: No, my deploy are ok, but when I develop something new I need to change in my application.properties and comment the spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/customers because when I run spring-boot:run to test my app the datasource don`t works ( or I dont know how configure)

Comment: Can you please explain, If you're using the embedded Tomcat, why in the world would you like to use a JNDI data source then?

Comment: because I use embeded tomcat to develop, after finish I deploy a .war in my client`s tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that what you want is to use different configurations for different environments.

What you need is taking advantage of [Spring Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html). By setting the variable `spring.profiles.active` you can define your current environment settings.

For example, in production, when you run your application, in your JVM settings you set a:

```
java -Dspring.profiles.active=production ...
```

But when  you're developing your application, in your IDE you set the settings to

```
spring.profiles.active=development
```

I typically do it using Spring Boot configuration [using YAML](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-yaml), and then I define environment specific settings by defining a [multi-profile document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-multi-profile-yaml):

```
spring:
  profiles: development,default
  datasource:
    url: "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:1543/jedis"
    username: "luke"
    password: "sk1walk3r!"
    driver-class-name: "org.postgresql.Driver"
spring:
  profiles: production
  datasource:
    jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/jedis
```

That way you can easily change the settings you use while working on development or debugging in your IDE, etc.

There is probably a way to do it using properties files as well, but I wouldn't know since I always use YAML.

Comment: Tks, I start to does this today, waiting for another possibility :D do you know can I set the spring.profiles.active=dev in intelij idea? tks

Comment: Menu Running->Edit Configurations... in the dialog, set the profile in the "VM Options" input box, you set it to `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev`. The `-D` is the Oracle/OpenJDK JVM options to set a system property. Consult `java -h` for more details.

Comment: can u help me? I using your solution, but I only have the application.properties and application-dev.properties, in my normal I have the spring.datasource.jndi-name prop, and in my -dev not, but when I run in dev mode, he load the spring.datasource.jndi-name from properties and I got error i think that r because he load then replace from -dev but I don`t have this in -dev file. how can I fix this?

Comment: after change to datasource I start to get the lazy load, I need to add another conf to fix this? tks

Comment: What do you mean by "fix the lazy load"?

Comment: Because when I in dev mode (using the properties in the sample) I don`t got the lazy load, but when I use in production with the tomcat datasource I got the lazy load. how Is the diff between them?